# Doctrine2 prevent default relation index

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have defined a new entity in symfony 2 using doctrine annotations. It has a many-to-one relation to another table and an unique index, using the same column `(parent_id, subset_index)`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="mapping", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="parent_subset_index", columns={"parent_id", "subset_index"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Mapping
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Record")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="RESTRICT")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="subset_index", type="integer")
     */
    private $subsetIndex;
}
```

A `doctrine:migrations:diff` generates the follwing MySQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE mapping (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    parent_id INT NOT NULL, 
    subset_index INT NOT NULL, 
    INDEX IDX_D87F7E0C727ACA70 (parent_id), 
    UNIQUE INDEX parent_subset_index (parent_id, subset_index), 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

As you see I end up with two indices over parent_id, the `IDX_D87F7E0C727ACA70` index is unnecessary.

How can I prevent doctrine from generating this index? I know I can edit the migration file, but then the index would be recreated everytime I run another `doctrine:migrations:diff`.

Comment: I think the `UniqueConstraint` is used to create a unique indexes on none key columns, which means whenever you use it with some columns you define in your table structure to make those fields unique; but whenever you create `ManyToOne` relationship, doctrine generates another index which indicates the foreign keys index and that's totally different from `UniqueConstraint` index. If you want to rename the relationship index, in doctrine you cannot do that.

Comment: I really hope an answer to this question. I have a table with millions rows, with latitude/longitude along user_id. I created an index on "user_id + latitude + longitude". With this index, distance requests are really quick (6ms), but Doctrine wants to create its own index on user_id. Then MySQL uses this index (don't know why), and my requests now lasts more than 12 seconds !